# How do i convert this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to convert this , so i didn't need to load a library

```
$('.mobile .pureCssMenu span , .tablet .pureCssMenu span').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: jQuery **is** Javascript.

Comment: i didnt want to load a jquery library on this page , what method can i use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll is used with css selectors:

```
var elements=document.querySelectorAll('.mobile .pureCssMenu span , .tablet .pureCssMenu span');
for(var i = 0;i < elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].onclick=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for in` to iterate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using the `forEach`, `call`, and `addEventListener` methods:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile .pureCssMenu span , .tablet .pureCssMenu span')
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        return false
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/yeceoxpz/)

Answer (score 1):

The better way:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile .pureCssMenu span , .tablet .pureCssMenu span');
for (var i = 0, il = elements.length; i <= il; i += 1) {
    addEvent(elements[i], 'click', function (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
        return false;
    });
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent(eventName, callback);
    }
}
```